# tips on invoking a method

Tags: java, methods, return, invoke

I'm trying to invoke the method from this string so that I can ask the client their username etc.

here is the code:

```
public String getNameFromClient(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {

try

{  out.println("Send name");
   String name = in.readLine();
   return name;
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("ChatClient err: " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}
}
```

i've tried getNameFromClient name = new Name(name);
I am familiar with OO programming with PHP but haven't done java for a few years so forgive me if my logic or skills lack!

Thanks

Comment: `Name name = new Name(getNameFromClient(in, out));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String nameString = getNameFromClient(in, out);
Name name = new Name(nameString);
```

Or you can do it in one line:

```
Name name = new Name(getNameFromClient(in, out));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Name name = new Name(nameString());
Is it going to compile?

Comment: It did. I just wrote sample. +1.

Comment: the main class is called ChatServer

Comment: I had to include the buffered reader and input stream to read messages coming from the client, then invoke the method with the (in, out) paramters. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you want is something akin to:

```
  final ChatServer myServer = new ChatServer ();
  final String nameEntered = myServer.getNameFromClient (in, out);
  final Name myName = new Name (nameEntered);
```

which is identical to:

```
  final Name myName = new Name (new ChatServer().getNameFromClient (in, out));
```

(eliminating variables, if they're not needed)

However, since this method does not seem to alter any properties of the `ChatServer` object, you might consider making it a `static` method:

```
  public class ChatServer { public static String getNameFromClient … }

  final String nameEntered = ChatServer.getNameFromClient (in, out);
```

Note that `static` methods are called using the class name, and don't require you to create an instance of that class (`new ChatServer`) before calling them.

However, if this is the chat server class, you might instead make `in` and `out` be properties, and avoid having to pass them in:

```
   public class ChatServer {
       private final BufferedReader in;
       private final PrintWriter out;
       public ChatServer (…) {
             …
             in = …;
             out = …;
       }
       public getNameEntered () {
             /* notice, not having to pass in & out now */
             /* just use the same ones saved as properties */
             …
       }
   }

   …

   final ChatServer myServer = new ChatServer (…);
   final String nameEntered = myServer.getNameFromClient ();
   final Name myName = new Name (nameEntered);
```

or

```
   final ChatServer myServer = new ChatServer (…);
   final Name myName = (myServer.GetNameFromClient());
```

Comment: it's currently in the public class named ChatServer

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you have:

1. An object "Name" which can be initialized with a String containing the name
2. A function (getNameFromClient) that returns a String object

you want to create a Name object, by getting the name String using a function.
This would be done like so:

```
Name name = new Name(getNameFromClient(in, out));
```

Why?
Name name is the declaration of your variable of type Name, it's only a pointer right now.

Then you say you want to make a new one (new Name(/*String with name should go here*/);
but you need the name String to initialize it.

The name string is what's returned by your function (getNameFromClient).
so you put it INSIDE the initialization constructor arguments. That leads to this:( I assume the buffered reader is named in and the print writer is named out here)

```
Name name = new Name(getNameFromClient(in, out));
```